# nest js how to pass value from config service into constructor or decorator or in database module initialization

Tags: nestjs, datasource, typeorm

```js
const mysql_sca = configuration().mysql_sca.connectionName;
  constructor(
    private configService: EnvService,
    private globalHttpService: GlobalHttpService,
    @InjectDataSource() private dataSource: DataSource,
    @InjectDataSource(mysql_sca) private mysqlDataSource: DataSource,
    private dbService: DbService,
    private chroniclesService: ChroniclesService,
    private commonIspService: CommonIspService,
  ) {}
```

`mysql_sca` value getting `undefined`

Comment: where does `configuration()` come from?

Comment: configuration() is costume configuration file similar to

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#custom-configuration-files